# fgets/scanf reading file gives no values

Tags: c, memory, opencv

I have a txt file containing numerous lines of unsigned character triples. The data comes from an OpenCV BGR picture, so each byte triple is a BGR Colour value.

When I try to read the file, the lines I'm reading in with fgets() are empty after maybe a third of the picture file.
Heres my code:

```
    FILE* DS;
    DS = fopen("Data.txt", "r");
    char line[100];
    for (int x=0; x<image->width; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<image->height; y++)
        {
            fgets(line, 10, DS);
            sscanf(line, "%c %c %c", &FrontTexture->imageData[FrontTexture->widthStep * y + x * 3 + 0], 
                                     &FrontTexture->imageData[FrontTexture->widthStep * y + x * 3 + 1],
                                     &FrontTexture->imageData[FrontTexture->widthStep * y + x * 3 + 2]);
        }
    }
    fclose(DS);
```

I'm sure that the lines are filled with three characters because I went into the file and looked at line x*y. Nevertheless I get only one blank character in my line after a third of the file.

Hope thats clear enough.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

a part of the txt file:

```
Z a `
Y ^ a
Z ` a
Y ^ a
Y _ `
Z ` a
Y a `
Z b a
V c a
X b a
V c a
V c a
V c a
V c a
T c a
T c a
S c a
S c a
R b `
R b `
U b `
W a `
W a `
Y a `
Z b a
[ b a
Z b a
[ c b
Y c b
Y c b
```

This was written to the file by:

```
for (int x=0; x<image->width; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<image->height; y++)
        {
            fprintf(DS, "%c %c %c\n",   FrontTexture->imageData[FrontTexture->widthStep * y + x * 3 + 0], 
                                        FrontTexture->imageData[FrontTexture->widthStep * y + x * 3 + 1], 
                                        FrontTexture->imageData[FrontTexture->widthStep * y + x * 3 + 2]);
        }
    }
```

EDIT2:

here is my text file:
http://www.2shared.com/document/SmLbhYzH/Datensatz.html
size: 6,15mb

EDIT3
the image data of my OpenCV image is just a character array that should be filled with b0 g0 r0 b1 g1 r1 ...

defined as follows:
char *imageData;

Comment: Just checking if I understood correctly - the file has `x*y` lines, and each of the lines has three numbers in it?

Comment: Is this actually C++? Might wanna lose the tag if not! Don't suppose you feel like sharing the values of width and height, and throwing the contents of Data.txt somewhere we can see them?

Comment: Are you sure that this file has the triplets as text, and not as binary values? Because you are reading them as if they were text...

Comment: Is the file binary, or text? This seems to imply it's a little bit of both, which is not making sense. If it's text, you can't use `%c` to have raw bytes in a line, since a pixel with a component value of 10 (line feed in ASCII) will then terminate the line. If it's binary, you can't parse it as if it consisted of lines.

Comment: its a .txt file with unsigned chars in it. that means you can open the file with an editor and you see letters. width and height: 640*480. the part of the file i'm reading contains definitely just single characters.

Comment: @unwind : I'm not sure. I saved the file myself before and I printed bytes with %c. But wouldn't some lines still hold the right values? Dont think every line after 1/3 of the file starts with "10"...

Comment: For such a fixed format, I'd actually suggest in reading six chars (three data, three whitespace) at once and parse them without using scanf and fgets, which will only bring you trouble.

Comment: @MartinHennig Do it the way Jonas suggests, that's the only way around your ambigous line endings that I can see ...

Comment: So I cant use fgets? because in my "line" from fgets, there are not 6 characters but only one blank space. How should I do this?

Comment: @MartinHennig - I'm able to read your whole file using `fgets()`. What makes you say `the lines I'm reading in with fgets() are empty`? Are you looking at the values being read or the characters being printed?

Comment: Well of course "line" is never empty, it just doesnt get updated after round about a third of a picture. this happens when reading the line with fgets and then trying to scanf the line.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the return values on those functions. See [fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) and [sscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf). Those return values are important and will tell you where things are going amiss.

Comment: That's a very good point (most people ignore those indeed), but I guess it should be a comment...

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall - It is a solution to the problem as the file may be incorrectly formatted. Besides it is good programming practice to use the return the values - the people that wrote the spec/code put them there for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

Using a code base very similar to yours I'm able to read the whole file:

```
unsigned char a, b, c;

DS = fopen("/home/mike/win_share/Datensatz.txt", "r");
char line[100];
while(fgets(line, 10, DS) != NULL)
{
    sscanf(line, "%c %c %c", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("%c (%d) %c (%d) %c (%d)\n", a, a, b, b, c, c);
}
```

I'm seeing you say this `I get only one blank character in my line after a third of the file` and then I'm wondering...

Are you verifying that the characters are read correctly by looking at the file? You know you have non-displayable characters in there correct?

```
x (120) o (111) m (109)
{ (123) t (116) s (115)  <-- I'm guessing this is the last line that looks OK
  (127) u (117) w (119)  <-- (127) DEL char won't show
� (129) z (122) | (124)
� (131)   (127) � (128)
```

---

Second thought... is your array index access correct? I'm not sure what `widthStep` is set to, but it could cause problems:

if `FrontTexture->widthStep == 1`, and `x == 0` and `y == 0`

```
[1 * 0 + 0 * 3 + 0] => [0 + 0 + 0] => [0]
[1 * 0 + 0 * 3 + 1] => [0 + 0 + 1] => [1]
[1 * 0 + 0 * 3 + 2] => [0 + 0 + 2] => [2]
```

Then on the next iteration: if `FrontTexture->widthStep == 1`, and `x == 0` and `y == 1`

```
[1 * 1 + 0 * 3 + 0] => [1 + 0 + 0] => [1]  // Overwrite the data in imageData[1]
[1 * 1 + 0 * 3 + 1] => [1 + 0 + 1] => [2]  // Overwrite the data in imageData[2]
[1 * 1 + 0 * 3 + 2] => [1 + 0 + 2] => [3]
```

Have you tried printing out a few steps to verify everything's working as you expect?

Comment: the texture I'm filling holds only spaces after 1/3, because some characters arent read correctly. that right? so you say i could also read them as integers (%d) and still later tread them as bytes?

Comment: that doesnt work, because the line I get with fgets() already holds only one space and the rest is ignored by sscanf. I dont know why your fgets() gives you the correct values of the file and mine wont. after fgets() if I debug and look at line, visual studio tells me its only a string with one blank space...

Comment: @MartinHennig - I suspect so, but I'd need to see your `FrontTexture` structure to say for sure if it's not being _stored_ correctly. My point here mostly is that reading the data via `fgets()` and `sscanf()` in a trivial way (as my example) is working fine. So the way you're reading the data is OK, but something else is amiss. Could you post your structure, and any allocation/initialization that you do for it?

Comment: @MartinHennig - I tried windows and Linux, VS10 and gcc, I'm seeing the data read correctly each time. I updated my answer with some debug suggestions for you, have you verified every few iteration that the loops are storing the data in the correct place?

Comment: widthStep means the complete width of one textureline, so its in my case 1920. i think the indexing is ok. i'll try putting my line values in single unsigned char variables like you did and will report. thank you for your time!

Comment: Didnt work, sorry. I saved the image afterwards to be sure and its one third of the picture and the right side is black. i used sscanf(line, " %c %c %c", &a,&b,&c ); afterwards is wrote a,b and c to the texture data.

Comment: new info: fgets returns NULL in the cases when line = " ". so there cant be any characters to read. please test if fgets never returns NULL in your test!

Comment: @MartinHennig - when `line = ` is that an empty string or a space?

Comment: Its a string with only a blank space.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
sscanf(line, " %c %c %c", ...
```

Note the space at the beginning of the string. That will avoid reading a blank as a valid first character.

Comment: Wasn't the OPs problem that `fgets` stops getting the data from the file after a while? I'm confused :S

Comment: Not very clear from the description... maybe... On second read, now I think that the file is binary, and he is reading it as if it were text.

Comment: I don't think it's binary since the OP said "I went into the file and looked at line x*y"... It's also "Data.txt", to me that implies that the file was created and should be accessed in text mode...

Comment: You are assuming that a "blank" is *not* a valid character. This is a poor assumption! The first character on each line is the value of the blue channel in a BGR pixel; it could be between 0 and 255. Even non printing values are perfectly valid here.

Answer (score 1):

We need to see a sample of the input file really. However there are a number of issues.

fgets will read at most 10 characters, if a line is 11 characters then the first call will read 10 of them, and the second the remaining one. 
You should also test what fgets returns, and for extra safety that sscanf is returning 3 - the number of things it matched.
The direct call to fscanf might be better, avoiding the fgets

```
fscanf(DS, "%c %c %d", ...
```

as that will handle spaces better.

Comment: Looks like the lines *must* be under 10 characters long, as the `sscanf` call only matches 5 bytes worth of content. I guess we'd need the input code to see whether there's a glaring logic error in that, however.

Comment: I think if you're using _only_ fscanf, you can run into trouble with fscanf skipping over whitespace, as indicated in the manpage: *A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.;
see isspace(3)). This directive matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input.*